# Slope on Existing Second Story Deck Needed

Tags: deck

I am buying this house and it has a second story deck/roof over the garage. It has access to the top via a door leading from the master bedroom. My understanding is that water does not flow off of it and the current cover is some type or roofing underlayment. Deck is solid and it would be nice to be able to use it. First off how would you make a slope so the rain does not pool on it and what type of flooring would you put on top of the current material. It would be nice to have some sort or waterproof tile or other type of flooring that would be attractive and functional. Advice please. Picture Location include location of deck and actual deck as well as where the water needs to flow off two.  Thank You.

[[image: Deck top][1]]

[image: view]

Comment: Start with checking your understanding. It would be highly unusual (and probably involve a lot of water damage below) to have no slope on that roof deck. If that's the case, unless you delete the door without a step, correcting it would be **very expensive.**

Comment: Not sure I follow. Are you saying it is ok the way it is? And if its not slope the only way to achieve this would be to remove one door, wall up that hole and put replacement siding in its place at then at that point I would be able to slope the roof?

Comment: I'm saying you should actually measure the roof slope before deciding what price you want to pay for the house, if you want to pay for the house at all. There are multiple ways to fix it, all require extensive work. Walling up that door is the least complex and therefore least expensive one I can think of. Rebuilding the entire roof frame (which might be needed anyway if it's actually dead flat and leaking in there rotting it out) will be *rather* more expensive but might let you keep the door. I consider the garage and deck as things having negative value in placing a bid on this house.

Comment: Walking away and finding a different house without this problem is very much worth considering, since you haven't bought it yet.

Comment: Yes walking away is an option. But getting house at a great deal so money is available if needed for repairs. Pier and Beam home. Having the foundation check today which is more of a concern. Under this deck and garage though is a slab. Waiting to hear back from inspectors today (Home,Foundation,Plumbing) and depending on there results will help me to keep or pass.

Comment: It could be that the garage roof _below_ the visible decking has the appropriate slope and is properly draining. If that's the case, then slope in the decking itself isn't nearly as important, because wherever the water may run off the decking boards, it'll hit the slope below and run off the garage roof below. (This is less likely, but still possible.)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the length of the run you wish to slop is 20' or 24' ? At 20' you will want between 2 1/2" to 5" of slope (1/8" per foot minimum and 1/4" per foot maximum). It appears that you do not have enough room to raise the deck under that door (the one without the step).

For waterproof decks above living space there are several ways to do it.

One way is to rip the slope into the top of the joists when building the deck- note this should be approved by the architect/ engineer for structural reasons. Then the plywood is fastened to that and usually metal L flashings at the walls (which go under your siding) and at the edges to which elastomeric urethane coatings are applied. Then tile is set onto that surface.

The second option is to frame your deck joists full height. Then you either add boards right on top of your joists which are ripped the appropriate slope or add lumber to the sides of the joists which run on the slope. Then you add your plywood subfloor and apply the same multi step elastomeric urethane coatings and tile on top of that. Both of these option use a lot of wood.

A third option is to build your deck level and apply the same waterproofing material. Then have you tile person build the slope with concrete (drypack) and tile over that. This is our most commonly used alternative. It does require that it is designed this way and has an engineers approval as it is a lot of weight (as you can imagine).

I do not think it is a good idea to put any permanent material (tile for example) over a rolled roofing waterproof job.

To do this properly, any option is a lot of work and costs.

Comment: So do you feel that other than spending a lot of money the alternative would be to leave it alone and not walk on it or use it as a deck?

Comment: Even if you "don't walk on it or use it", it's still there, collecting water on the flat roof above the garage. You're going to end up with garage roof damage from water collecting if there's truly no slope.